# Why am I getting "unrecognized selector" errors when subclassing GDataEntryBase from Google Data Objective-C Client Library?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3, google-data-api, google-provisioning-api

I've built the [Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) and have it linking and working with my application (incl. GTMOAuth2) and can pull data back. I need to work with the [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/) (still XML-only) so am building out the additions I need within my own application. I think I have finally figured out how all of this works and I'm *very* close to reading custom elements, but I'm missing something.

I've subclassed `GDataServiceGoogle`, `GDataEntryBase`, and `GDataFeedBase` and am getting correct data back. I'm starting with a simple & straightforward element type: `quota`. In the Users feed, the quota element looks like this:

```
<apps:quota limit="2048"/>
```

So, I've added the following value construct:

```
@interface GDataQuotaProperty : GDataValueConstruct <GDataExtension>
+ (NSString *)extensionElementURI;
+ (NSString *)extensionElementPrefix;
+ (NSString *)extensionElementLocalName;
@end

@implementation GDataQuotaProperty
+ (NSString *)extensionElementURI       { return kGDataNamespaceGApps; }
+ (NSString *)extensionElementPrefix    { return kGDataNamespaceGAppsPrefix; }
+ (NSString *)extensionElementLocalName { return @"quota"; }
@end
```

And I've added the following methods to my `GDataEntryBase` subclass:

```
- (GDataQuotaProperty *)quota;
- (void)setQuota:(GDataQuotaProperty *)val;
```

Implemented as follows:

```
- (GDataQuotaProperty *)quota {
    return [self objectForExtensionClass:[GDataQuotaProperty class]];
}

- (void)setQuota:(GDataQuotaProperty *)val {
    [self setObject:val forExtensionClass:[GDataQuotaProperty class]];
}
```

As [documented in the comments in `GDataObject.h`](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/BaseClasses/GDataObject.h) (and I've been working off of `GDataServiceGoogleCalendar`, `GDataEntryCalendar`, and `GDataFeedCalendar` as a reference implementation), in my `GDataBaseEntry` subclass I've implemented `addExtensionDeclarations` as follows:

```
- (void)addExtensionDeclarations {
    [super addExtensionDeclarations];

    Class entryClass = [self class];

    // User extensions
    [self addExtensionDeclarationForParentClass:entryClass
                                   childClasses:[GDataQuotaProperty class], nil];
}
```

However, when I try to call the `quota` method as follows in my callback:

```
GDataTextConstruct *titleTextConstruct = [user title];
NSString *title = [titleTextConstruct stringValue];
GDataQuotaProperty *quotaConstruct = [user quota];
NSString *quota = [quotaConstruct stringValue];
```

I get an exception and this error:

```
2012-11-19 12:42:22.667 Google Apps Open Directory Sync[47679:903] -[GDataEntryBase quota]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2836d0
```

In the above example I do get the user's name (the element's `title`) back correctly without error. Also, the `user` object is actually of the type of my `GDataEntryBase` subclass, not `GDataEntryBase` itself (verified in the debugger), plus the `classForEntries` method in my `GDataFeedBase` subclass  correctly returns the class of my subclass of `GDataEntryBase`) so between the two of those it *really* has to be the correct class. I have a breakpoint on my `GDataEntryBase` subclass's `quota` method which is never being tripped, so what am I missing here?

As mentioned, I've been comparing with the Service/Feed/Entry implementation for Calendar (specifically the `accessLevel` & `color` elements and methods) and am just not seeing what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: +1 because this is a pretty well formed & detailed question, and my first thought is that the library is looking for the base "`GDataQuotaProperty`" class and knows nothing about your subclass.  This might be something that *could* be accomplished with a category, I dunno.  I'll have to think about this a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that it is a possibility that the base class can't find the subclass. I have found a couple other examples of people using the Google Data Objective-C libraries and getting similar "unrecognized selector" errors that were resolved by fixing linking issues, so that is something I've considered (although `GDataObject.h` states "The real purpose of extensions is to allow elements to contain children they may not know about").

Comment: I've updated the question with a few more clarifications, esp. with regard to the `user` variable in `[user quota]` example call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I had implemented the `classForEntries` method in my `GDataFeedBase` subclass and was correctly returning the class of my `GDataEntryBase` subclass from it, as follows:

```
- (Class)classForEntries {
    return [GDataEntryUser class];
}
```

I had missed the implementation of `standardKindAttributeValue` in the same `GDataFeedBase` subclass, which should've been returning the appropriate category schema URL ("http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006#user" in the case of Google Provisioning API User feeds). So, I implemented as follows (although I actually use a constant):

```
+ (NSString *)standardKindAttributeValue {
    return @"http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006#user";
}
```

Once `addExtensionDeclarations`, `classForEntries`, and `standardKindAttributeValue` were all implemented correctly, `GDataEntryBase` was able to correctly determine that my subclass should be used for the objects in the feed and so my selectors were recognized.

Many thanks to Greg Robbins of Google for pointing me in the right direction [in this thread on the Google Data APIs Objective-C Client Libraries discussion group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gdata-objectivec-client/zbwzYKDTlgE/mWugfn-Ix9oJ).